# Object = nil after firebase request method

Tags: swift, class, object, scope

I am using firebase realtime database.
I request the data and I put it in an object I made using For loop
but if I want to use the object after the request method it's nul.
Here is the code and see comments
any suggesting ?

I try to use "class" , "struct" and "init"

```
var StockOb : [StockModel2] = []
var tempstock : [StockModel2] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.StockOb = [StockModel2]()
        self.tempstock = [StockModel2]()
}
func getdata() 
{
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("MyStock").observe(.value) { (snapchot) in

            let AllStock = snapchot.value as! NSDictionary



            for (key,_) in AllStock {

                let ab = StockModel2()
                let OneStock:NSObject = AllStock[key] as! NSObject
                ab.name = OneStock.value(forKey: "name") as? String
                ab.quan = OneStock.value(forKey: "quan") as? Int
                ab.price = OneStock.value(forKey: "price") as? Int
                ab.total = OneStock.value(forKey: "total") as? Int







                self.StockOb.append(ab)
            }
            /// here it's ok 
            print("[+] iside firebase method = \(self.StockOb[0].price!)")
            self.tempstock = self.StockOb
        }
        /// here it's nil
        print(self.tempstock[0].name) // nil
        print(self.StockOb[0].name) // nil
}
```

This is my object :

```
class StockModel2 : NSObject{
    var name :String!
    var quan : Int!
    var price : Int!
    var total : Int!


}
```

I want to use my object any where I want after I add it to "self.StockOb" or "self.tempstock"

Comment: start var names with small letter

Comment: Don't just toggle between class and struct and whatever else you tried hoping it will work. Understanding what they are and why they won't (and didn't) solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
/// here it's nil
print(self.tempstock[0].name) // nil
print(self.StockOb[0].name) // nil
```

you access the variables outside of firebase callback , so you will get a crash

```
func getdata() {

    let ref = Database.database().reference() 
        ref.child("MyStock").observe(.value) { (snapchot) in

            let allStock = snapchot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]  
            Array(allStock.values).forEach { 
                let ab = StockModel2() 
                ab.name = $0["name"] as! String
                ab.quan = $0["quan"] as! Int
                ab.price = $0["price"] as! Int
                ab.total = $0["total"] as! Int 
                self.stockOb.append(ab)
            } 

            self.tempstock = self.stockOb 

        /// here it's not nil
        print(self.tempstock[0].name) // here
        print(self.stockOb[0].name) // here
    }
}
```

Also you don't have to write this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
self.stockOb = [StockModel2]()
self.tempstock = [StockModel2]()
```

because they initated in declaration here

```
var stockOb : [StockModel2] = []
var tempstock : [StockModel2] = []
```

Comment: i want to access variables outside .. if u can give me Suggestion about it ? i write ur code and still having nil outside

Comment: ok .. i found a solution thank u sir .. i made another func to set the variable .. but i have another issue .. after i get the array it's coming two array double .. example : if the total of prices is 2000USD .. after i get the array i got 4000USD

Comment: you need to do any upcoming processing end of the callback , show your current code and problem